# How to store the text given from the input to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js

From what I know I should modify the post function, but I don't know exactly how to add the new json object to the JSON file. What I would want to happen to the JSON file after the post function is having a 4th element, just like the others already existing 3.

The JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "author": "John",
        "comment": "How are you"
    },
    {
        "author": "Alex",
        "comment": "Hello"
    },
    {
        "author": "Maria",
        "comment": "Good morning"
    }
]
```

Node js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

var someObject = require('./bd.json')

app.use(express.json())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, access-control-allow-origin")
    next();
  });

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({Status: 'OK'});
})

app.get('/comments', (req, res) => {
  res.send(someObject);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

EDIT: I added the HTML part
HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                getComments();
            }

            function getComments(){
                fetch("http://localhost:3000/comments")
                .then((data) => { return data.json() })
                .then((json) => displayComments(json))
            }

            function displayComments(data){
                let responseArea = document.getElementById('responseArea');
                for (let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                    let authorName = document.createElement('P');
                    authorName.innerText = data[i]["author"];
                    let commentContent = document.createElement('P');
                    commentContent.innerText = data[i]["comment"];
                    let someRespone = document.createElement('DIV')
                    someRespone.appendChild(authorName)
                    someRespone.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'))
                    someRespone.appendChild(commentContent);
                    someRespone.style.border = "1px solid black";
                    responseArea.appendChild(someRespone);
                }

            }

            function sendInformation(){
                let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                let comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;

                fetch("http://localhost:3000", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
                    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
                    headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
                    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
                    body: JSON.stringify({name: name, comment: comment})
                }).then((data) => {
                    return data.json()
                }).then((json)=>{
                    if(json.Status === 'OK'){
                        document.getElementById('responseArea').innerText='Information receieved';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('responseArea').innerText='Information was not received';
                    }
                    console.log(json);
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Name:
        <input id='name' type='text' placeholder="name"/>
        </br>
        Comment:
        <textarea id='comment'> </textarea> 
        <input type='button' value="Send" onClick="sendInformation()">
        <div id='responseArea'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're using Node... mongoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read the file first convert it to an object then back to json and write to the file system. Here is an example with your code.

```
    app.post('/', (req, res) => {
      fs.readFile('file.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        let obj = JSON.parse(data); 
        obj.push({
          author: req.body.author,
          comment: req.body.comment
        }); //add some o
        let json = JSON.stringify(obj); 
        fs.writeFile('file.json', json, 'utf8', (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err
          }
          console.log('the file has been saved')
           res.send("succes")
         });
       }
    })
 })
```

Comment: I have tried this code and for some reason only creates a json object with the comment, the author is missing

Comment: There is no reason for this to happen unless you don't pass the author in the `req.body`

Comment: I found the problem, the html code used name instead of author. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: One more thing, even though the Json file has the new name+comment objects, if I refresh the page it still shows the same 3 comments, so in order to show the new introduced ones I would need to call "node index.js" in terminal again

Comment: read the file when you make the get request with `fs.readFile...`

Comment: app.get('/comments', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('bd.json', 'utf8', (err, data) =>{
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    someObject = data;
  })
  res.send(someObject);
})

Comment: It works, but for some reason I have to refresh the page 2 times to see the new comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use node `fs` module to read and write your json data into json file.

First you need to read all the comments from the file which includes old comments. 
Then convert that to `Object` and append the new comment and save.

**Sample Code**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const someObject = path.join(__dirname, 'bd.json');

app.use(express.json())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, access-control-allow-origin")
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  /* Sample code */
  fs.readFile(someObject, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) { // Read the old comments 
    if (!err) {
      const comments = JSON.parse(data);
      if (comments && comments.length > 0) {
        comments.push(req.body);
      } else {
        comments = [];
      }

      fs.writeFile(someObject, comments, (err) => {  // Write back the all comments with the newly added comment.
        // throws an error, you could also catch it here
        if (err) throw err;
        // success case, the file was saved
        console.log('saved!');
        res.send({ Status: 'OK' });
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    }
  });
  /* Sample code */
})

app.get('/comments', (req, res) => {
  res.send(someObject);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```